# Is there anyway to integrate Junos app with an iOS app to connect to a VPN?

Tags: ios, vpn

I am making an iOS app that will talk to a web service running in a private network via a VPN tunnel, I need a way to integrate my app with the Junos Pulse App.

Is there an SDK with documentation, a tutorial or any resource that can help me communicate with Junos app.

Comment: Hi Amogh, I am looking for a similar api. can you please let me know if you got any ?

Comment: In my case, I did not use any API client. agreed that the user will have to specifically connect to VPN using Junos Pulse app and then use our app otherwise, it will use Reachability class and tell the user that cant connect to  the Server and give him possible reasons, one of which being VPN not connected.

What you can do is, check this link.
http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos-pulse-30/topics/task/access-control-connect-sa-iphone-web-launching.html

You can launch Junos, if installed form using the app's URI scheme.
and pass few params that will autofill the login form.

Comment: My situation is a bit different. I just want to know if there is an api in objective-c which gets the username/password entered in the junos pulse iOS app ? Is there any api ?

Comment: Did you visit the link I gave you ?
See the URI scheme.
junospulse://<server-host>/<server-path>?method={vpn}&action={start|stop}
&DSID=<dsid-cookie>&SMSESSION=<smsession-cookie>&username=<username>
&password=<password>&realm=<realm>&role=<role>
Fill te details as as specified.
This will launch the Junos pulse and and you could connect to the VPN.

why do u want to access credentials from Junos app. You cant access data of another appp directlyin iOS.

Comment: I have a VPN connection through Junos Pulse in the iPad in order to be in the organization's network. Junos Pulse uses my ntid/password to establish a VPN connection in the iPad.
I want to implement SSO authentication with the Active Directory for my iOS app. I don't want to do it by calling a webservice which will authenticate with active directory. I want to have the user authenticated with the active directory in the iOS app itself.
Is there a way to accomplish this given the above scenario ?

Comment: Hi Amogh, Can you please provide me the sample code to execute the url mentioned above in an iOS app ?

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your url here"]];

this is the standard method to open any url in iOS.
if the scheme is http or https, it will open in Safari.

If the scheme is for one of the apps, it will open that app and pass the parameters to that app.
You fill these parameters with appropriate values to launch junos pulse with those values.

in this case scheme for Junos Pulse is junospulse:// so use it.
pass the username ,password, server path, method and other details.

Comment: Hi Amogh, Thank you for the details. I am able to launch the junos pulse and it pre-populates the username/password and establishes the vpn connection.Is there a way that we can suppress the junos pulse app from launching and just do the authentication and vpn establishment at the background and pass a status of the vpn to the iOS app. ?

Comment: I don't know much about it. Directly connecting to a VPN network without user coming to know, could be considered a security issue by Apple.
This is like logging into Facebook without showing facebook login,permission view or enablingit in settings for iOS6.

What you could do is, once the user is authenticated, save the authentciation locally and use Reachability to verify if the user can connect to network in case he loses the connection.

Comment: Hi Amogh, Thanks for the instant reply. Is there a way atleast to close the junos pulse application programmatically from within the iOS app once the authentication is done ?

Comment: nope man, have you ever noticed facebook app or safari getting closed when u login into an app via a social network. every app is sandboxed, you can't control one app from another app, thats totally insecure!

If you are developing this app for a client, tell him the limitations clearly :)

In iOS 6 you have VPN connectivity in settings, you dont even need JUNOS pulse.

Comment: Thank you Amogh. Can you point me to any link about the iOS 6 vpn connectivity ?

Comment: I meant that you have to enable i from settings in iOS 6. you cant do it programmatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to detect iphone's VPN connectivity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285093/how-to-detect-iphones-vpn-connectivity)

Answer (score 0):

I already answered on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300840/getting-user-credentials-from-junos-pulse-inside-a-ios-app), but answering here too in case someone finds this one:

Junos Pulse (or Pulse Secure now) has an AppConnect SDK, this is straight from their [guide](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/software/pulse/guides/Junos_Pulse_AppConnect_Deployment_Guide.pdf):

> The AppConnect SDK is a set of APIs and libraries, provided by Juniper, that allows mobile application developers
>   to directly open socket-based SSL VPN connections to a Connect Secure Gateway. From the point of view of the Connect Secure Gateway, these tunnels mirror all other forms of AppConnect tunnels. The integration is done at the code level. Any application that integrates with the AppConnect SDK needs to be recompiled and manually deployed to the end users. The AppConnect SDK is best leveraged by container solutions or in-house applications that are deployed without the use of an MDM solution. The APIs include authentication and connection management functions. Connections can be shared across multiple applications on a single device. Contact your Juniper sales representative for more details regarding AppConnect SDK.

Unfortunately as you can read in the last paragraph it is only available through your organisation Juniper sales representative.

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers.  Instead, flag to close this question as a duplicate of the other.

Comment: I cant flag it as duplicated because the answer is not accepted, if it gets accepted I will flag this one according. Sorry if it's not the way to do it, just wanted to throw some info on something that is not well documented.